# Preparing site build for release

Tags: build, web, workflow, release, production-environment

Our company developing websites for over 1 year. At this stage we rised a question: What is algorithm of moving web site from local enviroment to the production? We already have our own flow, but we're pretty sure, that there are experienced companies that have something usefull, that might be used in our own.

Our flow (simple) looks like this:

1. Pull version from git
2. Upload to remote server
3. Updating configs and static files on remote server (if needed)
4. Optimization of CSS\JS
5. Switch to production

Questions:

1. Our main issue that we don't have any automated(coded on our own) scripts that push version from git to staging server. Does anybody do this at all?
2. Each step: pull from git, upload to server, changing configs, optimization of CSS\JS is made separatly by personal call. Is this good practice?

Maybe we're missing some key point?
Would appreciate any help or tips to our flow. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: why optimizing CSS / JS  is done after uploading to remote server ?

Comment: Do you think it's better to do it before upload?

Comment: yes. Before any production deployment, all codes / scripts (except config files) should be frozen.